# How to query 'Not Equal to' in boto3 dynamoDB python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am new to AWS and python. I have been trying to get the records from dynamoDB using boto3 in python. Could anyone please suggest how to get records when value1 not equal to value2. I am able to query with `eq` but not `ne`. Below is my code.

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('Id').eq('123') & Key('status').ne('Booked')
)
```

I am getting below error when I execute the above code.

```
Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: 'Key' object has no attribute 'ne'.
```

Answer (score 1):

KeyCondition don't include `ne` operator for the sort key
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.KeyConditions.html

You will need to user FilterExpression instead :

`FilterExpression : 'status  <> :Booked', ExpressionAttributeValues : {':Booked' : 'Booked'}`

Answer (score 1):

KeyCondition does not include ne. It's only available for filterExpression.  But filterExpression can't have any of the primary key (neither partition key nor sort key).  If you are trying to add not equal condition to a sort key, there were suggestions to create a GSI and use that sort key as a regular attribute instead.

I am stuck in the same situation and hope this help.

[image: link from aws]

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this.
Here's an issue from 2019 requesting the feature:
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2168

In the meantime I've had to do something like this:

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('Id').eq('123')
)
items = filter(
    lambda item: item['status'] != 'Booked',
    response['Items']
)
```

Not a perfect solution (if lots of records come back with the query you'll have problems) but will work in my situation where there is a pretty limited number of records per `Id`.